Understanding すぐ帰るから留守でも私に待っているように
I need help understanding the bold sentence from Kokoro chapter 10:

私はそのうち先生の留守に行って、奥さんと二人差向いで話をする機会に出合った。先生はその日横浜を出帆する汽船に乗って外国へ行くべき友人を新橋へ送りに行って留守であった。横浜から船に乗る人が、朝八時半の汽車で新橋を立つのはその頃の習慣であった。私はある書物について先生に話してもらう必要があったので、あらかじめ先生の承諾を得た通り、約束の九時に訪問した。先生の新橋行きは前日わざわざ告別に来た友人に対する礼義としてその日突然起った出来事であった。先生はすぐ帰るから留守でも私に待っているようにといい残して行った。それで私は座敷へ上がって、先生を待つ間、奥さんと話をした。

I understand すぐ帰るから留守でも私に待っているように as "I will be back soon, so even if you house sit, make sure to wait for me." Is でも a combination of て-form of だ and も? 私に待っている means "wait for me" right? If so, what's the difference between 私に待っている and 私を待っている?

First of all, you might be confusing 留守 with 留守番: 太郎は留守だ means Taro is absent. 太郎が留守番をしている means Taro is house-sitting.

先生は，すぐ帰るから留守でも私に待っているようにといい残して行った

This 私 does not refer to the 先生 himself: this 私 is the same guy as 私 in other part of the paragraph, and used this way as an indirect speech.
Not exactly the same but basically identical to:

先生は，すぐ帰るから<私>に留守でも待っているようにといい残して行った

Sensei left, telling (via Sensei's wife) that he will be back soon, so <私> should wait even if Sensei is absent (when 私 arrives).

Thank you for the answers! But, 留守 can also mean 留守番, no? In the first sentence of the paragraph, 留守 in 私はそのうち先生の留守に行って... means 留守番.

@weeab00 It depends but sometimes yes. But I would read this first paragraph as "(There was an occasion when) I visited Sensei in his absence...", because Sensei's going out to Shin-bashi was unplanned and 私 had no intention to go for house-sitting. (Even without this background, I would prefer this interpretation in this specific sentence but couldn't come up with a compelling reason why.)
